# Run a initial Liquibase script

Tags: liquibase

This is my 2nd day using Liquibase. 
I have a 'backup' or 'Repositry' with the database that I need to create locally on my PC.

I have looked at the documentation, but Im realy not 100% clear on how to run it.

Ive updated the `Liquibase.properties` file to reflect the correct paths and username and passwords.

How do you run the update command to generate the tables and test data.

Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Liquibase documentation on '[Adding Liquibase to an existing project](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html)' is probably the best place to start. Basically, you want to set the properties file so that it refers to the existing 'backup' database, and then run `liquibase generateChangeLog`

This will connect to the existing database and generate a file that contains the structure of the existing database expressed (typically) in an XML file called a changelog. You then create a new properies file that will connect to your local database and use `liquibase update` to apply the changelog to the local database and populate the structure. Note that this does not typically transfer the *data* from the existing database to the new database, just the structure - the tables, keys, indexes, etc. If you want to have test data as well, you can either export that data from the existing database, or you might look into crafting the changesets manually. To export the data, a command like this would be used:

`java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile="./data/<insert file name> " --diffTypes="data" generateChangeLog`

Comment: Thanks Steve. I managed to get it "going", but Im having a problem in the script. Maybe you can help me, but I'll post it in a separate question. and send you a link. Thanks

Comment: Here is a link to the other question.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27033231/2240163