# Unexpected error running Liquibase: Invalid `addFulltextConstraint`

Tags: liquibase

Okay so Im new to Liquibase and this might be a silly question, but...

Im running a update script to generate the database.
When I run the script I get this message (well this is a scaled down version to make it more readable ).

This script was created by someone who has been doing it for a while, but Im trying to figure out if its a bug or if Im doing something wrong. Anyway here is the output.

`liquibase update`

`Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error parsing line 5076 column 153 of 01_base.xml: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element`

`'addFulltextConstraint'`

`:validCheckSum
:preCondition 
:tagDatabas 
:comment
:createTable
:dropTable
:createView
:renameView
:dropView
:insert
:addColumn
:sql
:createProcedure
:dropProcedure
:sqlFile
:renameTable
:renameColumn
:dropColumn
:mergeColumns
:modifyDataType
:createSequence
:alterSequence
:dropSequence
:renameSequence
:createIndex
:dropIndex
:addNotNullConstraint
:dropNotNullConstraint
:addForeignKeyConstraint
:dropForeignKeyConstraint
:dropAllForeignKeyConstraints
:addPrimaryKey
:dropPrimaryKey
:addLookupTable
:addAutoIncrement
:addDefaultValue
:dropDefaultValue
:addUniqueConstraint
:dropUniqueConstraint
:customChange
:update
:delete
:loadData
:loadUpdateData
:executeCommand
:stop
:output
:empty
:rollback
:modifySql`

`is expected.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard "addFulltextConstraint" change available in Liquibase. Is there a custom extension that has been written to support it that needs to be included in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, after some searching and soul searching I discovered that.